# How to delete a user based on time last logged in?

Tags: python, database, ubuntu, nosql, griddb

I am an administrator for a GridDB database, and I would like to delete inactive users. I would like to check the last time a user was active, or when last they logged in to the database. If it's been more than 6 months ago, I want the user to get deleted.
I saw on (this website)[https://mohammaddarab.com/find-last-login-date-sql-server-login/] that one could get the last login time with:

```sql
SELECT MAX(login_time) AS [Last Login Time], login_name [Login]
FROM sys.dm_exec_sessions
GROUP BY login_name;
```

But I'm not sure if that's available for GridDB.
The work environment includes a GridDB Python client on a Linux machine (Ubuntu) and a GridDB container is storing the database. Is there any way I could achieve this?

I tried to search the internet for a solution and I found the code above, I want to create a GridDB replica of that code, or something similar, as long as it works.